# How to append existing html Header tag in javascript/jQuery with some text and setting its font size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show my header content as "Rolling App       Hello, SanjayB" where Rolling App is static content to left side of header whereas Hello, SanjayB i.e. Appended text should be at right side of header with font size as 10.

I am trying to do this but no luck

```
$("#mainheader").html("<h2>Rolling App </h2>"+"<p font-size: 5px;>"+appUserName+"</p>");
```

Comment: @Cerbus: I am not using CSS and also about setting it fontsize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(function(){
    $("#mainheader").append("<h2>Rolling App "
     +"<span style='font-size:10pt;'>"
     +appUserName+"</span></h2>");
});
```

**[working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AeVKB/16/)**

Comment: 1 upvote. i am happy to accept this as answer. But this 'Rolling App hello, SanjayB' is coming like 'Rolling App' and new line 'hello, SanjayB' , i am running this on mobile and using worklight

Comment: In jsfiddle link provided, it is in same line.

Comment: please see my answer, I am wraping span inside h2 tag.

Comment: Yes, i agree and i understand that, but same i am porting on mobile as android app.

Comment: screen size may be the concern, as this much text is not able to fit into mobile screen.

Comment: I am accepting this as answer, well i see screen resolution as problem. Will checkout some workaround